# ARANGODB AQL MATCHES() with nested objects not possible

Tags: nested, match, arangodb, aql

I use `MATCHES()` AQL function to search for entries in the arango database matching an example. This feature works nice for plain examples, but I cannot get it work properly with the nested features. See example:

```
RETURN MATCHES(
{ "a" : { "c" : 1 }, "b" : 1 },
{ "a" : { "c" : 1 } },
false
)
```

This returns `true`, however if I try:

```
RETURN MATCHES(
{ "a" : { "c" : 1, "b" : 1 }},
{ "a" : { "c" : 1 } },
false
)
```

It returns **`false`** !! (I expected to return true)

I have read that this is known in the `Query by example` section
https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/data-modeling-documents-document-methods.html#query-by-example

Their solution is to use dot notation, but it does not work in AQL

Following their example:

```
RETURN MATCHES(
{ "a" : { "c" : 1, "b" : 1 } },
{ "a.c" : 1 },
false
)
```

returns `false` (and I would expect to return true)

How can I then, use the `MATCHES()` for nested attributes?

FYI: I use arangodb v3.5.5-1

Clarification:
I want to get a match of `{ "a" : { "c" : 1, "b" : 1 } }` by giving  `{ "a" : { "c" : 1 } }` as example

I've posted the Issue in ArangoDB repository: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/12541

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the document you expect it to find?

Comment: I have edited so the three examples contain the same example type. The "problem" is known here https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/data-modeling-documents-document-methods.html#query-by-example This solution works with collection.byExample() function but not with raw AQL, and I don't know how to make it with AQL

Answer (score 0):

`MATCHES` compares attributes - it doesn't care what type the attributes have, so if you are trying to match nested objects, they have to have the same attributes/values; it follows that you can not have arbitrarily deep structures overlayed and checked for correspondence.

In the given example you can pick out the substructure with `LET` and use `MATCHES` against that

```
LET doc = { "a" : { "c" : 1, "b" : 1 }}
LET a = doc.a

RETURN MATCHES(
  a,
  { "c": 1}
)
```

To leverage the arangojs capability to use paths to peek into the structure, you can write a user function that uses query by example and call that from AQL (https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/extending.html).

Nota Bene: The arangodb client library of your language should provide convenient access to registering user functions (e.g. `class AqlUserFunctions` in `arangodb-php`).